# TFloatAnimation leaving "afterimages" when dynamically creating components

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am having issues with the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Rectangle:TRectangle;
Animation: TFloatAnimation;
begin
Rectangle := TRectangle.Create(Self);
With Rectangle do
  begin
    Parent := Form1;
    Height := 65;
    Width := 65;
  end;

Animation := TFloatAnimation.Create(Rectangle);
with Animation do
  begin
    Parent := Rectangle;
      PropertyName := 'Size.Width';
      StartValue := 65;
      StopValue := 120;
      Trigger := 'IsMouseOver=true';
      TriggerInverse := 'IsMouseOver=false';
      Interpolation := TInterpolationType.Cubic;
  end;
end;
```

Whenever my mouse cursor leaves the created rectangle, it leaves an "afterimage" as shown below:
[image: "Afterimage" after the inverse of the Animation]
How can I fix this?

Whenever I tried increasing the duration of the Float Animation, it did not leave the afterimage. However, I am required to have a faster animation without the slow-down of having a long animation.

Comment: this is FMX, isn't it?

Comment: yes @complete_stranger

Comment: From `PropertyName := 'Size.Width';` remove `Size`. Iow, use: `PropertyName := 'Width';`

Comment: Tom is right. For some reason changing size of FMX components using `Size.Width` does not notify parent component/control that it needs updating. I'm not sure whether this is by design or a bug.